# Django Rest framework: passing request object around makes it lose POST data in newer version

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm upgrading a site from Django 1.4 to Django 1.9

I have a view passing control to another view like this:

```
@csrf_protect
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
def preview(request, project_id, channel_type, format=None):        
    return build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=True, format=format)

@csrf_protect
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
def build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=True, builder=None, build_after=True, format=None):
pass
```

The problem (never occurred before) is that, when passed from `preview()` to `build()`, the request object loses its POST content.

How to solve this?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to understand the issue. What data is being posted? How do you know it is being lost? Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: It's just a POST request with a single key / value. I know that it's lost because inspecting request.POST in the preview() method, I see my key / value pair and right after, within build(), it's an empty dictionary

Comment: Try using `request.data` to access `POST` data.

Comment: What version of DRF did you upgrade from and to ? Or has it remained the same?

Answer (score 8):

You could just separate out the logic you're storing in the `build` view into a common function used by both endpoints without any decorators e.g. `_build` – this way whatever is happening within the decorators shouldn't occur in the case of the call within `preview`.

```
@csrf_protect
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
def preview(request, project_id, channel_type, format=None):        
    return _build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=True, format=format)

@csrf_protect
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication,))
def build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=True, builder=None, build_after=True, format=None):
    return _build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=preview, builder=builder, build_after=build_after, format=format)


def _build(request, project_id, channel_type, preview=True, builder=None, build_after=True, format=None):
    pass
```